# How can you load html text from pure html?

Tags: html

Is there a way to include the content of one HTTP request (containing either text/html or text/plain) in another HTML file? Of course this can be done via AJAX or on the server side, but I'm interested in a pure browser HTML way. Perhaps using a `<link>` tag, or some HTML5 method I'm not familiar with?

For example: 
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p>This is my text loaded from the original document</p>
    <p>This is text I want to load from another file: <span id="other"><!-- link other resource here --></p></span>
</body>
</html>
```

otherResource.html:

```
<p>This is from another resource</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

```
<iframe src="page.html" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about including text from another page, such as a footer or header, and just trying to find a way to include that, you might try a template engine.

Template Information: http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/templating-engines-9134396

For example with EmbedJS from the link above:

```
new EJS({ url: "template.ejs" }).render({ name: "Jack" });
```

would allow you to include a template in a file called template.ejs.

Another option is to use a tool, such as Dreamweaver to accomplish it.

Finally you could do it with a script before you put the html on the server.